# Python unittesting: adding test methods dynamically?

Tags: python, unit-testing

My unit tests are complex and it's not easy (or impossible) to program them manually case by case. What would be beneficial is to be able to add test data dynamically and, for readability, having an own test method for each one of them, preferably by generating test methods on the fly.

Here is a (non-working) example:

```
class TestParam(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, _):
        dir = 'test_param_items'
        for f in os.listdir(dir):
            if os.path.isfile(dir + "\\" + f) and f[0] != '_':
                print f
                func = self.TestCaseFactory(f, dir)
                setattr(TestParam, func.__name__, func)
                super(TestParam, self).__init__(func.__name__)


    def TestCaseFactory(self, inFileName, inDir):
        def func(inObj):
            print inFileName
            with open(inDir + "\\" + inFileName, "r") as testFile:
                testNode = testFile.read()
                par = Param(inETree=etree.XML(testNode))
                self.assertEqual(testNode, etree.tostring(par.eTree))
        func.__name__ = "test_" + inFileName[:-4]
        return func
```

And test files, here, are ordinary XMLs.
But Python 2.7's test runner takes test methods from class and not from instance, and runs them by instance:

```
loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
```

so I cannot run my generated test functions.
My mistake is obviously that usually a test method covers many test cases but I think it's very time consuming to write 10s and 100 of these methods. And it would be quite messy for me to have a bunch of test cases per method and when a test (method) fails to search for the actual AssertEquals method output with a huge data.
And I would find an approach of

```
def testMethod1(self):
    load('testFile1')

def testMethod2(self):
    load('testFile2')
```

etc. quite much desintegrated (test data and test methods are separated into different files).

Any ideas of this? Is my approach wrong? Any possibility to make it?

Any idea of this approach?

Comment: I've used [`ddt`](https://github.com/datadriventests/ddt) for this in the past. I think `pytest` may also support something similar.

Comment: @Gyula Hi, so if I am understanding your question, is it: A general practical and quick guideline how to write unit tests on python? Or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: :-) Not exactly. What I'm asking about is to reduce repeated working while divide test cases into individual test method for each case. Computing is much about automation and I'm about that.

Comment: Have a look at the [parametrized test fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) of `pytest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I've managed to solve this purely based on Python 2.7's infrastructure by calling in TestSuites:

```
#modules of the tested objects not included here
from TemplateMaker import Param
from lxml import etree
#/

import unittest
import os
import os.path


class TestSuiteParam(unittest.TestSuite):
    def __init__(self):
        self._tests = []
        dir = 'test_param_items'
        for f in os.listdir(dir):
            if os.path.isfile(dir + "\\" + f) and f[0] != '_':
                # "_test_filename" is for inactive/switched off tests 
                tp = TestParam(f, dir)
                self.addTest(tp)
        super(TestSuiteParam, self).__init__(self._tests)


class TestParam(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, inFile, inDir):
        func = self.TestCaseFactory(inFile, inDir)
        setattr(TestParam, func.__name__, func)
        super(TestParam, self).__init__(func.__name__)

    @staticmethod
    def TestCaseFactory(inFileName, inDir):
        def func(inObj):
            with open(inDir + "\\" + inFileName, "r") as testFile:
                testNode = testFile.read()
                par = Param(inETree=etree.XML(testNode))
                inObj.assertEqual(testNode, etree.tostring(par.eTree))
        func.__name__ = "test_" + inFileName[:-4]
        return func
```

Note that this solution is still not perfect (for some reason TestCase instance can have only one testmethod, since its parent's **init**() handles only one), but works.